# Image in Phaser3 is not showing

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I need to show an image on my first screen in phaser3 here is the code

```
//logo.js
class Logo extends Phaser.Scene{
    constructor(){
        super('Logo')
    }
    preload(){
        this.load.image('gameLOGOFinal', './assets/gameLOGOFinal.png');
    }
    create(){
         
        this.add.image(400,300, 'gameLOGOFinal');

        setTimeout(() => {
            this.scene.start('Start')
        }, 20000)
    }
}
```

the image is on the right path but it only show a green box
[image]

BTW I am using XAMPP apache to run it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that the image has been loaded? Open Dev tools in the browser > Network tab and see if the request with suffix 'assets/gameLOGOFinal.png' has returned status OK. If not, see what request is being sent and what request you want to be sent.

Comment: I did. Its okay now thanks for your answer it helps too

Comment: @Bianxzy how did you solved it?